# Smooth an existing "image" in C#

Tags: c#, antialiasing

How can I smooth a `Graphics` object in C# ? To be more precise, I need to run a smoothing at a very precise moment of my `Graphics` object generation, on the whole object. The image is coloured.

I am flexible in terms of input classes (`Graphics`, etc..). I just suggested `Graphics` at it is a central class for image manipulations in C#.

`Graphics.SmoothingMode` is out of context for what I need to do and I imagine WU's algorithm only applies to drawing lines in greyscale.

Comment: You did not mention what you are trying to antialias. Is it a bitmap or vector shapes?

Comment: it is a bitmap. As further precisions, I am interested mostly in anti-aliasing colored shapes that have edges with the white background.

Comment: This is a good resource I have found but is for smoothing rather than antialiasing : http://www.smokycogs.com/blog/image-processing-in-c-sharp-smoothing-using-convolution/

Comment: To be clear: you are loading an aliased `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and you want to draw it onto a graphics object with anti-aliasing?

Comment: I have loaded initially a Bitmap in a Graphics, done some operations already, then need to anti-aliase (maybe passing back to bitmap, then again to Graphics is an option at this stage) , then do further operations on the Graphics and render.

Comment: I am sorry you are still not making much sense to me. Could it be you simply need to set your `Graphics.InterpolationMode` property?

Comment: I need to anti-aliase my Graphics at one point in time. I don't want to/can't anti-aliase whatever I print in there, which is what setting InterpolationMode does.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20111/discussion-between-rotem-and-franklin)

Comment: Sorry, I can't access that page with my proxy..

Comment: InterpolationMode only affects the .DrawImage method
while SmoothingMode affects vector drawing.
If you want to only anti-alias one particular DrawImage call, you can set the InterpolationMode before and after the call. It is not possible to anti-alias an aribtrary image after the fact. You may blur it, but it is hardly the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the image processing features of [AForge.Net](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/). It is an open source framework that includes a lot of useful image processing capabilities. You will find many smoothing filters among them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you used the wrong words to describe your problem. Anti aliasing refers to (as Hand mentioned) the point in time when individual objects are drawn for the first time. For instance, when drawing a diagonal line on an empty surface.

You already have an image, and you want that image to be smoothed. I suggest you detect edges in the image using a standard algorithm, then smooth those edges. I am not familiar with the exact process to do this myself, sadly.